# Как проверку условия "if" на 3 отдельных слова? Python

Tags: python, if

Я ломаю голову, а в гугле ничего не нахожу казалось бы простой вопрос.

Как проверить условие оператора if на то, имеется ли 3 слова отдельно написанных?

У меня в голове это выглядит так:

ЯП: python

```
If [word][word][word] == 3:
   условие
```

Но я понимаю что это не так, ведь мне надо чтобы строка имела 3 отдельно написанных слова

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду под фразой ```отдельно написанных```?

Comment: Ничего не понятно, но нажму на 'Отслеживать этот вопрос'

Comment: Может нужно проверить что строка имеет 3 слова? Или что в списке 3 слова?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нам нужно разделить строку по пробелу с помощью функции `split` и посчитать количество слов в получившемся списке с помощью `len`.

```
text = 'Раз два три'
words = text.split()
if len(words) == 3:
    print('Строка состоит из 3 слов, разделенных пробелом!')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = 'a b c'
as = a.split()
len_a = len(as)
if len(len_a) == 3:
    print("Успех")
```

Comment: Спасибо работает!

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял ваш вопрос:

```
words = ['word1', 'word2', 'word3']

if len(words) == 3:
    print("Успех")
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает

Answer (score 1):

```
my_str = 'Моя строка тут'
if str.count(my_str , ' ') == 2:
   pass
```

Comment: Этот вариант не сработал

Comment: Этот вариант рабочий надо просто понять логику. Два пробела между строк значить три слова. Слов всегда больше чем на 1 пробел. Правельно str.count( ' ')

Comment: Так нужен аргумент, нельзя просто оставить скобки

Comment: а в целом вариант мне больше всех понравился по смыслу

Comment: Аргумент пробел